# What is a "low dimensional manifold" in this context?

Tags: probability-distributions, manifolds

What does this sentence mean? I only know undergrad-level calculus, probability & linear algebra - and [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1701.04862.pdf) sentence doesn't make sense to me (Appendix B):

[image]

Here is another [example usage](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1701.07875.pdf) of this:

[image]

## Questions:

1. What does "low dimensional manifold" mean in this context? ([I don't understand wikipedia explanations here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manifold#Classification_and_invariants))
2. Why is it only low dimensional... does a higher dimensional manifold *not* have this property? I would think that higher-dimesional something has all the same attributes of a lower-dimensional something.
3. What do I need to learn to understand this?

I hope I phrased the question clearly - if you need more details please let me know.

Comment: The absolute size of the dimension isn't the problem here, just the relative dimension and the idea is that the distribution is supported on some lower dimension "manifold" in the ambient space -- but you don't need the mathematical development of a manifold, just think locus, surface whatever

Answer (score 8):

In this context, "low-dimensional" just means "lower than the dimension of the ambient space".  So for instance, if $X$ is a random variable that takes values in $\mathbb{R}^3$, it might actually be concentrated on a subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$ whose dimension is smaller than $3$ (like a line, or a plane, or a surface), and then it could be continuous but not absolutely continuous.  For example, if $X$ is uniformly distributed on the unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^3$, then $X$ is continuous, since it has probability $0$ of being at any single point.  However, it is not absolutely continuous, since the unit sphere has Lebesgue measure $0$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$, and $X$ does not have any probability density function in $\mathbb{R}^3$ (if such a thing existed, it would morally have to be sort of like $\delta$-function supported on the sphere but $0$ everywhere else).

For the passages you've shown, it's not important to understand any of this in technical detail (such as the precise definition of a "manifold" or how one defines "dimension" rigorously); these are just examples of why we are interested in probability distributions that do not come from density functions.

Comment: I think I kind of understand the first part. What about the "This is not the case in the rather common situation where we are dealing with distributions supported by low dimensional manifolds". I don't understand why this is _not_ the case of low dimensional manifolds... is it the case for "higher" dimensional ones? :-o

Comment: Also, I don't understand what a probability distribution that does not come from density function is. I thought they all did, except for discrete ones, which have pmf.

Comment: The second quote is pretty much exactly the same as the first.  It's talking about a density function $P_\theta$ not existing if your probability distribution happens to be concentrated on a low dimension manifold (i.e., a subset of your space of lower dimension than the full space).

Comment: A probability distribution is just any rule that tells you the probability of your random variable taking values in some set.  When you have a density function, the probability is given by integrating the density function over the set.  But a probability distribution does not have to come from a density function in this way.

Comment: For second quote, it sounds to me like what they are saying is that this is not the case for distributions with low dimensional manifolds, but it **is** the case for distributions with higher dimensional manifolds. So why can't we find $P_\theta$ on a higher dimensional manifold instead?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "instead".  Sure, you could consider a distribution which does have a density function, but then you're talking about a different distribution than the one you started with.

Comment: So "low dimensional manifolds" is equivalent to saying that a probability distribution is discrete (not continuous)?

Comment: No, that's almost exactly the opposite of the main point here.  The point is that a distribution can be concentrated on a low dimensional manifold but still be continuous (since the low dimensional manifold is not a discrete set).

Comment: Do you mean the boundary of the sphere, or the entire sphere, has a Lebesgue measure of 0? I'm assuming you meant the boundary...

Comment: @DavidRefaeli: In math "sphere" refers to the boundary.  (The interior is instead called a "ball".)

Comment: @EricWofsey thanks for clarifying

Comment: @EricWofsey for the second quote, in that paper, the author said the solution is "add a noise term to the model distribution". If I understand correctly, you mean if $P_\theta$ dimension is lower than $P_r$ dimension, it is impossible to find the KL divergence. If it is correct, do you have any idea how add noise solves the problem?

Comment: @Toby: Well, the noise would make the model no longer concentrated on a subset of low dimension, since it is instead "fuzzed" out over a neighborhood of that subset.

Comment: @EricWofsey so it works as the regularization to prevent overfitting in machine learning, but how can it solve the problem that $P_r$ and $P_\theta$ have different dimension? At first, I think the solution is try to increase the number of dimension of $P_\theta$

Comment: @Toby: Yes, as I said, you change what the model is, which means you change $P_\theta$.

Comment: @EricWofsey I see, thank you